# SQL Server into vb.net declaring variables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net-2010

I have my code here from SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT * FROM tblProduct

DECLARE @NewStocks INT

SELECT @NewStocks = SUM(Stocks + 2) 
FROM tblProduct 
WHERE ItemCode = 8

PRINT @NewStocks

UPDATE tblProduct 
SET Stocks = @NewStocks 
WHERE ItemCode = 8

SELECT * FROM tblProduct
```

With this code I'd produced what I want which is to select the specific `ItemCode` (column of mine), then add the `Stocks`, then update that in the table which specifically into `Stocks` (column of mine). BUT AS I DO IT IN SQL SERVER 2012 PERFECTLY (for me. Sorry I'm just a newbie) I have now my problem in my VB.NET program.

```
    SQL.AddParam("@StocksItemCode", txtStocksItemCode.Text)
    SQL.AddParam("@AddStocks", txtStocksAddStocks.Text)

    SQL.ExecQuery("DECLARE @NewStocks INT;")
    SQL.ExecQuery("SELECT @ NewStocks = SUM(Stocks + @AddStocks) FROM tblProduct " & _
                  "WHERE ItemCode=@StocksItemCode;")
    SQL.ExecQuery("UPDATE tblProduct " & _
                  "SET Stocks = @NewStocks WHERE ItemCode=@StocksItemCode;")
```

As you can see I just go with the same logic that I did in SQL Server 2012. BUT I got an error of :

> ExecQuery Error:
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@NewStocks".

How can I fix this? If you, reading this cannot get specifically what I want please bear with me and I will try to edit it so you can get my thoughts.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of 3 separate batches, execute a single batch with the `DECLARE`, `SELECT`, and `UPDATE` statements.

Comment: I get you thoughts but I don't know to do in vb.net. Can you help me?

Comment: You also have a space SELECT (at) NewStocks